# Python Script for reference node in abaqus

Tags: python, abaqus

I want to create a reference node using python for abaqus. In the input file, I can easily do it, as below:
*Node
      1,  x,y,z
*Nset, nset=SET-1
 1,

But I am struggling to do it by scripting it. I have an orphan mesh, so I don't have a part. Could someone provide some insight into this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: You should explain a little more the problem you want to use

Comment: i think you need to use the keyword editor. see for example  http://stackoverflow.com/q/35572838/1004168

Answer (score 0):

If you mean a reference *point* (which seems to be the case from the informations you provided), you can just use (for example in the python console in CAE)

```
# Assign the rootAssembly to a (just to shorten a little bit the next command)
a = mdb.models['Your model'].rootAssembly

# Create a reference point at (x,y,z)
a.ReferencePoint(point=(x, y, z))
```